# Convert data frame to specific formatted JSON in R

Tags: json, r

I am trying to create a specific JSON output in order to hit a specific cell tower API. Here is the format that each of the requests must be in

```
{
"token": "Your_API_Token",
"radio": "gsm",
"mcc": 310,
"mnc": 410,
"cells": [{
    "lac": 7033,
    "cid": 17811
}],
"address": 1
}
```

I am attempting to create this format in R from my data frame using two different methods and two different data frames. Using the first data frame

data_frame_1

```
  cid  lac mcc mnc
1 2241 130 91  2
2 4356 123 91  2
3 3456 124 91  2
4 9801 160 91  2
5 6757 160 91  2

for (i in rownames(data_frame_1)){
  data<-print(toJSON(list(token = "1asdfghjkl", 
radio =  "gsm", mcc = 91, mnc = 2, cells = data_frame_1[(i),1:2]), pretty = TRUE))
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
    {
  "token": ["1asdfghjkl"],
  "radio": ["gsm"],
  "mcc": [91],
  "mnc": [2],
  "cells": [
    {
      "cid": "2241",
      "lac": "130"
    }
  ]
}
```

This output is very close to the final output that I would like to have, except there are square brackets around the first four components that I do not want in the output.

Here is the second method and data_frame being used:

data_frame_2

```
  token      radio  mcc  mnc  lac  cid
1 1asdfghjkl   gsm   91   2    130  2241
2 1asdfghjkl   gsm   91   2    123  4356
3 1asdfghjkl   gsm   91   2    124  3456
4 1asdfghjkl   gsm   91   2    160  9801
5 1asdfghjkl   gsm   91   2    160  6757

data<-toJSON(unname(split(data_frame_2, 1:nrow(data_frame_2))), pretty = TRUE)
```

Here is the output:

```
 [
{
  "token": "1asdfghjkl",
  "radio": "gsm",
  "mcc": "91",
  "mnc": "2",
  "lac": "130",
  "cid": "2241"
}
  ]
```

I would like to be able to modify either of the lines to be able to produce the output needed to write the json to the output needed to make the request.

Comment: To remove the boxes, you can add the `auto_unbox = TRUE` parameter to the `toJSON` function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that you have to do is add the parameter `auto_unbox = TRUE` to the `toJSON` function.

```
for(row in rownames(data_frame_1)) {

  list(

    token = "1asdfghjkl", 
    radio =  "gsm", 
    mcc = 91, 
    mnc = 2, 
    cells = data_frame_1[(row), 1:2]

  ) %>%
    toJSON(pretty = TRUE,
           auto_unbox = T) %>%
    print


}
```